# ListView Common Control (mscomctl.ocx) not installed under Excel 2016 / Windows10

Tags: vba, windows-10, excel-2016

I'm using Windows 10 and Excel 2016 and I tried to install the Windows Common Controls (SP6) using the file mscomctl.ocx. It ran perfectly under Excel 2013 but not under Excel 2016. I'm looking for the `ListView` control which does no longer run on the new machine.

I performed the following steps:

1. Copy the mscomctl.ocx file from a running Windows 10 / Excel 2013 into the folder C:\Windows\SysWow64
2. Register the file with the cmd prompt regsvr32 C:\Windows\SysWow64\mscomctl.ocx
3. Referenced the mscomctl.ocx in VBA which then appeared in the list with a checked box
4. Checked the registry and theres only an entry for Version 2.2. Altough on the running machine I've got 2 entries: (Standard) & PrimaryInteropAssemblyName) where on the not running machine there's only the (Standard) entry.

Step No. 5 would have been adding the control to the Standard controls but None of the common controls does appear in the list.

Does anybody have experienced similar issues? If yes, could you resolve them?

Many thanks
Adrian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because `mscomctl.ocx` is a 32 bit only item. It will not work in 64 bit mode.

Addendum: in July 2017 Microsoft published a 64-bit version of `mscomctl.ocx`, thus since then it **is** possible to use its controls from Office 64-bit. The 64-bit version of `mscomctl.ocx` is also part of newer Office versions (like Office16). A good article about using `mscomctl.ocx` with Office 64-bit is available [here](https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=mscomctl-treeview-x64-access).

Comment: @sporty21 The question is what version of Office was installed, 32-bit or 64-bit? It doesn't matter that Windows is 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of coping the file from somewhere, you could always download them from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=10019)

Make sure the "Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6)" reference does point on the SysWoW64 folder. If not Use the "Browse" button to select it.

Left click on the "Toolbox" -> "Additional Controls", make sure the "Selected Items Only" is not checked, and look for the "Microsoft ... 6.0 (SP6)" controls.

Note that you might experience issues when trying to open the resultant workbook in older versions of Windows and/or Excel.